# AS3 - How can I generate a random number?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I generate a random number in Flash CS5 using AS3, I'd prefer it as simple as possible.

My attempt gives me an error:

```
day_gross.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, randomNumber);
function randomNumber(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var randint:Number = Math.random();
    trace(randint);
    }
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: A variable being null 1009. Do you see anything wrong with this code?

Comment: @Noah - It seems likely that `day_gross` is null. Make sure it's been created before the call to `addEventListener`. If you are using Flex, you may need to perform this code in an event listener for the MXML's `FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE` event.

Comment: Never mind. it was that I mistyped something.

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend either deleting this question or marking my answer below as correct.

Comment: I am going to mark it correct.

Comment: Seems questionable to mark the answer as correct when it didn't actually solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Math.random()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29) to generate a pseudo-random number.

If you are generating numbers for the purposes of cryptography, however, you should use [`flash.crypto.generateRandomBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/crypto/package.html#generateRandomBytes%28%29) (requires FP11)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire How is my answer not helpful? The question did not require random _integral_ numbers and both answers use `Math.rand()`?

Comment: See the answer with more upvotes. He goes to explain exactly how and provide code samples. The original question posts code that already uses Math.random(), just not correctly (based on the requirements). You basically just post what he's already done.

Answer (score 9):

`Math.random()` returns a random number between 0-1.

The following code create and traces a round number between 0 and the maximum value of uint:

```
var randomUint:uint = uint(Math.random() * uint.MAX_VALUE);
trace(randomUint);
```

This next code example defines and logs a rounded number between the minimum and the maximum value of int (with negative numbers too):

```
var randomInt:int = int.MIN_VALUE + int(Math.random() * Number(int.MAX_VALUE + int.MIN_VALUE));
trace(randomInt);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private function randomIntBetween(min:int, max:int):int {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Comment: WARNING! This function produces an uneven distribution.  The below Monte Carlo simulation shows the 'edge' numbers have roughly half of 'inner' numbers...

`var a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
 a[this.randomIntBetween(2,6)]++;
}
for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
 trace(j+": "+a[j]+", ");
}`

yielded the following results "0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 12422, 3: 25028, 4: 24752, 5: 25212, 6: 12586, 
7: 0,"

Comment: You are right @Sean, A solution would be to use `Math.floor` and compensate by adding `1` to the minimum value like this: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get it to work is this. when you click on a button it generates a random number. it is self explainatery

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var numbers:Array = new Array(49);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
    {
        numbers[i]=i;
        numbers[i] =[Math.round( Math.random()*i)];
        resulttxt.text = numbers[i];
    }
}
<s:Button top="342" label="Generate" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" horizontalCenter="0"/>
<s:TextInput id="resulttxt" left="10" top="65" width="250"/>
```

This work for me. try it out